# How to create a footprint with a pad on the component side in gEDA pcb

Tags: pcb-design

I've read a bunch of tutorials, but can't figure out how to do this.  What I want is a pin where the pad is on the component side instead of the solder side and the hole is plated so that it can be connected to a trace on the solder side.  Most of the parts on this board will have pads on the solder side as usual.  Is there a way to force this when creating a new footprint (this is what I would prefer since this particular part will generally be handled this way)?  If not, can it be done when laying out the board using a footprint that would normally put the pad on the solder layer?

Comment: Are you talking about gEDA PCB or KiCad's PCBnew ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow quite what you want.  Simply having a pin will have anulars on both sides of the board and plated through - there's no option not to.